# Pandas "trimming" invalid date values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an Excel file showing the following:

```
my_date 
00/01/1900  00:00:45
```

When I try to read from pandas:

```
df = pd.read_excel("...", dtype=str)
```

It shows me the following:

```
00:00:45.473000
```

I also tried specifying the engine and even using openpyxl directly:

```
import openpyxl

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("...", data_only=True)
sheet = workbook['Export']
sheet['A2'].value
```

But I keep getting `00:00:45.473000` instead of `00/01/1900  00:00:45`.

What do I need to do to read exactly how Excel shows?

Thank you!